# Micronaut/RxJava controller not returning output to client

Tags: rx-java2, server-sent-events, micronaut

I want to insert a record in a table every second, and log the result to the client. I got it 'almost' working: the client never receives any output. I came up with the following example class, to illustrate the problem, where I removed the DB stuff. WHo can help me fix it, i.e. I want to get a line of output streamed to the client after every second?

```
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.QueryValue;
import io.micronaut.http.sse.Event;
import io.micronaut.scheduling.TaskExecutors;
import io.micronaut.scheduling.annotation.ExecuteOn;
import io.reactivex.BackpressureStrategy;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

@Controller("/test")
public class TestController {

  @Get(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
  @ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)
  public Publisher<Event<String>> index() {

    return Flowable.create(
        subscriber -> {
          boolean active = true;

          while (active) {
            try {
              String docId = String.format("/testdoc/doc-%s.xml", System.currentTimeMillis());
              subscriber.onNext(Event.of(String.format("Inserted doc %s", docId)));
              Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
              subscriber.onError(t);
              active = false;
            }
          }
          subscriber.onComplete();
        },
        BackpressureStrategy.DROP);
  }
}
```

Comment: Relevant example server code is at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-examples/blob/5daf6f0dd090d3c2888ceb274d77c074bcaa38d8/petstore/storefront/src/main/groovy/example/storefront/StoreController.groovy#L71-L76 and https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-examples/blob/5daf6f0dd090d3c2888ceb274d77c074bcaa38d8/petstore/offers/src/main/java/example/offers/OffersController.java#L57-L63 and corresponding client code is at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-examples/blob/5daf6f0dd090d3c2888ceb274d77c074bcaa38d8/petstore/frontend/react/src/home/Home.js#L13-L17.

Comment: Do you really want to tie up a thread with `Thread.sleep(1000)`.